# Appropriate notation for denoting a multivariate student's t distribution?

Tags: joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, notation, t-distribution

Suppose, we have a vector variable $\mathbf{Y}=[y_1,y_2]$, such that $\mathbf{Y}\sim N(0,I)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then the bivariate distribution $P[y_1\leq Y_1,y_2\leq Y_2]$ can be denoted by $\mathbf{\Phi}(Y_1,Y_2)$. What would be an appropriate notation for such bivariate distribution, when $\mathbf{Y}\sim t_{\nu}(0,I)$?

Comment: Anything you like.  Only the most general notation, like "$\Phi,$" is commonly understood and even then you should define it the first time you use it.